# Deleting a database table in PHP spits out weird errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a MySQL database table in PHP. How should I go about this? I've tried the following code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($database_credentials['serv'], $database_credentials['user'], $database_credentials['pass'], $database_credentials['name']);

mysql_query($con, "DROP TABLE carts");
```

Which returns:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /setup_tables.php on line 2
```

I can't understand however, why it would be expecting a string. I tried changing it to look like this:

```
mysql_query("DROP TABLE carts", $con);
```

But that must be syntactically incorrect, as it spits out a resource error. How should I go about doing this?

**Appendation**: The table is populated if that makes any difference.

Comment: It looks like it might come from a different part of your code:
`in /setup_tables.php on line 2`

Comment: You can't mix and match mysqli_ and mysql_

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing mysqli_* and mysql_*. Your connection is object of MySQLi, but your query is mysql_*.

The fastest fix you can do is to change:

```
mysql_query($con, "DROP TABLE carts");
```

to

```
mysqli_query($con, "DROP TABLE carts");
```

http://php.net/mysqli_connect

Comment: Ingenious! I didn't realise it was simply a typo, what an idiot. I've been working around this for hours not understanding why it would not successfully execute when others would.

Comment: @Jamus We all start somewhere =) Although do check out [**PHP The Right Way**](http://www.phptherightway.com/), which will of stepped over these kind of issues for new starters in PHP and actively maintained by the GitHub community. Problem is when there's 1000 of resources, all saying different things at different era's of PHP versions, stay ahead of the Outdated versions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I need to recommend that you use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) instead of [mysql](https://www.php.net/mysql_query), because it's deprecated,

Second, you swapped the query and resource parameters, This would work

```
mysql_query("DROP TABLE carts", $con);
```

Or (if you use mysqli)

```
mysqli_query($con, "DROP TABLE carts");
```